# What does "by a lot" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it have any special meaning here or just mean "a lot"? Is the period before "By a lot" correct?

"Is Hillary more powerful than Trump? That isn’t the right way to look at it. Hillary was just a candidate at the time. Trump is actually president. But the market ignored Trump and listened to Hillary.
The market believes that Hillary’s threat was more credible than Trump’s.
**By a lot**."

Source:http://www.businessinsider.com/stock-market-news-investors-dont-care-about-donald-trump-anymore-2017-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hillary's threat was more credible by a lot" has the same meaning as "Hillary's threat was a lot more credible".

"A lot" is a quantifier which makes things "bigger". Here, it refers to credibility as if it were measurable. It says that Hillary's threat to the American drug market was *more* credible and had greater implications. It then gives "the difference in credibility", or *how-much-more-credible-it-is*, as being very big.

So to clear it up again: "By a lot" is a quantifier applying to credibility.

Note that "By a lot." can be a sentence on its own, but is not grammatical. It is used to replicate that pause in spoken word caused by finishing a sentence and then adding more detail in another poorly formed sentence. "It is more credible. by a lot."

Answer (score 0):

It means that "**Hillary’s threat was many times more credible than Trump's**".

We use **by** to talk about measurements, and increases and decreases in amounts:

- By how much more than Trump's was Hillary's threat credible? - By a lot.